# populate div with data from jquery ajax post request to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, response, populate

I have a jquery function in my view that post a request to the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                var form = $('form');
                form.submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: form.prop('action'),
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: form.serialize(),
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            console.log(data);
                        }

                    })
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

the route spits back an array of objects:

```
Route::post('modelsearch', function () {

    $brand_id = Input::get('brand_id');
    $size_id = Input::get('size_id');

    $models = DB::table('pants_models')
        ->where('brand_id', '=', $brand_id)
        ->Where('size_id', '=', $size_id)
        ->get();

    return Response()->json(array($models));


});
```

I want to manipulate the returned array and post the html to a `#results div` in the view.
How do you do it in the callback success function? I can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking. You can manipulate the data right in your js success call.

```
success: function(data)
{
    //data contains the response from the route. So manipulate the result here and append them to the #results div.
    var html = '';
    for(obj in data){
    //Do stuff to build html
    }
    $('#result div').append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick unless I missed something. Suppose your route spits an array containing `result1` and `result2` keys:

```
success: function(data)
{
    $('#results').append(
        '<p>Result 1: '+data['result1']+'</p><p>Result 2: '+data['result2']+'</p>';
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the data into the div then create a string using that data and append that data into the #results div as :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var resultStr = "";
for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
    resultStr = resultStr + "<div>" + obj[i].column_name + "</div>" ;   
}

$("#results div").html(resultStr);
```

If there is anything else you want then please let us know.

Comment: I am trying this code. I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" which should mean json is being parsed twice. So I modified this line `var obj = JSON.parse(data);` into `var obj = (data);` but still can't see any result in my div, unless I am trying to access the data in the wrong way... i also modified the response to `return Response()->json(($models));` so that instead of an array of objects it spits out every single object as associative array, yet nothing apears using say `obj[i].name`

Comment: I was finally able to print the data using this code: `success: function(data)
                        {

                            var obj = (data);
                            console.log (obj);
                            var resultStr = "";
                            for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
                                resultStr = resultStr + "<div>" + obj[i].column_name + "</div>" ;
                            }

                            console.log(resultStr);

                            $("#results").html(resultStr);
                        }`

Comment: Chris you have to manage other code at your end. I have just sent you logic for the same.